# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin (get XML from android)

Tags: android, jquery, xml, ajax, webview

I've researched about this problem.
Everywhere people get this error because of reading local file from localhost. Also almost everywhere people need a json.

In my case i want to get [this](http://www.revotech.am/smarthome/app/xml/config.xml) xml file from this site from android (WebView). So can anybody explain what's wrong? What should I do to get it?

Here's my code:

```
$.get('http://www.revotech.am/smarthome/app/xml/config.xml', function(xmlData)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assue you are using Android version JELLY_BEAN or above and the javascript is running in the context of a file schema - If YES then do the following.

webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

From the Android documentation:

> Sets whether JavaScript running in the context of a file scheme URL
>   should be allowed to access content from any origin. This includes
>   access to content from other file scheme URLs. See
>   setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(boolean). To enable the most
>   restrictive, and therefore secure policy, this setting should be
>   disabled.
>
> The default value is true for API level ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1 and
>   below, and false for API level JELLY_BEAN and above.